# Why does 'X' mean close?

Tags: icons, symbols

It's well known that `X` symbol means close (and in some contexts dismiss or hide), but why/where was this symbol initially chosen?

My only thought was that when you want to "cancel" information on printed paper it is crossed-out and that led to `X`, which is similar to crossing out an item, becoming a symbol for cancel ([like GTK](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=gtk+cancel+images)) which was then again re-purposed as close, but I have no evidence of this. Is there a history behind this symbol?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [semiologic point of view](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_mark#See_also):

> An x mark (also known as a cross, x, ex, exmark or into mark[1](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_mark#See_also)) is a
>   mark (x, ×, X, ✕, ☓, ✖, ✗, ✘, etc.) used to indicate the concept of
>   negation (for example "no, this has not been verified" or "no, I don't
>   agree") as well as affirmation (for example in election ballot papers
>   or in x marks the spot). It is often used opposite the check mark or
>   tick (or the O mark used in Japan, Korea and Taiwan).

The [UI history point of view](https://medium.com/re-form/x-to-close-417936dfc0dc) (based on semiotics as well) dates it to **Atari TOS 1.0**, and later it resurfaced in Windows 95:

> [x] is a true icon, not representing a letter but representing an
>   action, and only adopted to represent ‘close’ well after the
>   development of graphics-oriented operating systems. The first
>   appearance of [x] in GUI design was likely the Atari TOS, possibly
>   influenced by the Japanese batsu and maru conventions. Thanks to a
>   last minute design change in Windows 95, and the mass adoption of
>   Windows worldwide, [x] has become the standard symbol for ‘close’, a
>   symbol that dominates web, app and software design today.

I've also heard the version of x representing crossed arms as in "defense" or "don't want", but really couldn't find anything to support this claim, so take it with a pinch of salt, just mentioning because always found this curious and maybe someone can shed a light on this

**EDIT:** re-reading the link I posted, the "crossed arms" is elliptically mentioned in the article. The concept of [*batsu*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_gestures#Two-hand_gestures) is actually 2 arms crossed:

> **Batsu**. In Japanese culture, the batsu (literally: ×-mark) is a gesture
>   made by crossing one's arms in the shape of an "X" in front of them in
>   order to indicate that something is "wrong" or "*no good*".

so guess the version is correct

Comment: +1 while this answer perfectly answers the question as a side note  I would very much like to know why X was decided as a concept of negation (and checks for affirmation for that matter)

Comment: +1 very nice to also bring in the historic background.

Comment: Consider the big red X at the end of a runway to mean "make no landing here"